# FirstOrDefault does not return null on list of integers

Tags: c#, linq

When I use `FirstOrDefault()` on an empty list of integers or booleans, I get `0` or `false` instead of `null`.

I understand this is by design, as it returns `default(T)`, but how do I force it to return `null` instead?

```cs
var emptyList = new List<int>();

emptyList.FirstOrDefault() == 0; // I want to receive null instead
```

Answer (score 5):

To make `FirstOrDefault()`, `LastOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` return *null* as the default value on lists of *values* (rather than *references*):

Cast your elements to *nullable* using `IEnumerable<T>.Cast<T?>()`.

```cs
var emptyList = new List<int>();

emptyList.FirstOrDefault() == 0;
emptyList.Cast<int?>().FirstOrDefault() == null;
```

- `IEnumerable<T>.FirstOrDefault()` will return `default(T)` when there is no result.

  - When T is a **value type** / **struct**, like *int*, it will return `default(T)`, e.g. for `int` that would be `0`
  - When T is a **reference type**, or **nullable value type**, like *int?*, *bool?* or a *class*, then it will return `null`, as `default(int?) == null`.

Comment: Updating to be consistent with microsoft documentation (value types vs reference types)

Answer (score 2):

That's why it is called `FirstOrDefault` and not `FirstOrNull`. The latter would mean that return type would differ from element type in case of value types (`T` vs `Nullable<T>`).

*(I see that you have already answered your own question, so I just complete it with the `FirstOrNull` extension method as a general solution):*

```cs
// the generalized version of Bouke's answer for the problem:
public static T? FirstOrNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    where T : struct
    => source.Cast<T?>().FirstOrDefault();
```

And of course, if performance matters you can improve it further:

```cs
public static T? FirstOrNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    where T : struct
{
    // Shortcuts for special cases. FirstOrDefault also has something like this
    // (but it's not quite useful on the enumerator returned by Cast<T>)
    if (source is ICollection<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection.Count == 0)
            return null;
        if (collection is IList<T> list)
            return list[0];
    }

    // general solution
    using var enumerator = source?.GetEnumerator() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    return enumerator.MoveNext() ? enumerator.Current : default(T?);
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `ICollection.Count` is not guaranteed to be fast (e.g. for `ConcurrentDictionary` it is quite slow).

Comment: You are completely right about `ConcurrentDictionary`, that's why (among others) I created an [alternative](http://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Collections_ThreadSafeDictionary_2.htm) for it ([source](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/blob/be14d6073688f74b4101ed9e34dc4233ef6282e7/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/Collections/ThreadSafeDictionary.cs#L126)). Anyway, when dealing with interfaces, no one can guarantee anything...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a list of Nullable<T> you could roll your own extension method that returns null, if a list of structs/primitives contains no item, else the first match.

```
            public static T? FirstOrNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Predicate<T> validator = null)
                    where T : struct {
                
                foreach (var item in collection) {
                    if (validator?.Invoke(item) != false) {
                        return item;
                    }
                }
                return default;
            }

//invocations

            int[] list = new int[0];
            int? match = list.FirstOrNull(); // => null
            list  = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            match = list.FirstOrNull(i => i == 42); // => null
            match = list.FirstOrNull(); // => 1
            match = list.FirstOrNull(i => i % 3 == 0); // => 3
```